# How to calculate the distance between all nodes of a graph MatLab

Tags: matlab, graph, distance

I have a graph G, and I want to find the distance of each pair of nodes. For directly connected nodes the distances(G) matlab function will return 1, there i want to find the distance as if these two nodes were not directly connected.

Comment: So you want to break that edge and call distances?

Comment: How do you define distance?

Comment: I assume the graph is unweighted?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes. Like this. but my graph has 10.000 nodes and very few edges. So the for loop is not helpfull.

Comment: @beaker Yes it is unweighted

Comment: @CrisLuengo distance is the number of nodes in the shortest path i think.

Comment: @Panagiotis. I'm not sure I understand why. How else do you plan on telling the BFS what to do?

Comment: @MadPhysicist i dont want to change the algorith of BFS. I need to change the graph dynamically. function distances(G) creates an NxN matrix with the distance from node i to j. Let A be the adjacency matrix of G. If A[i,j]=1 then distances returns the value 1. I want to calculate the distance as if A[i,j]=0

Comment: @Panagootis. What is stopping you from setting the elements between the nodes of interest to 0 manually and calling `distances`? You can always set them back to 1 after.

Comment: @MadPhysicist this is time wasting. My graph has 10.000 Nodes so this is a for loop that never ends.

Comment: @Panagiotis. That's only because magic doesn't exist. Imagine conceptually what you are trying to do.